# Existe a possibilidade de juntar dois arquivos de áudio em um só em android?

Tags: android, áudio

Exemplo: Audio A + Audio B = Audio C. Preciso que os sons se juntem mesmo, não concatenem.

O formato pode ser WAV, mas preferia que fosse MP3.

Encontrei alguns exemplos na net, mas nenhum funcionou.

```
protected Void myMethod() {
    List<String> selection = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    selection.add("a.wav");
    selection.add("b.wav");

    isProcessingOn=true;
    int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 0;
    try {
        DataOutputStream amplifyOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ssmultitrackPlus/project1/NOVO.wav")));
        DataInputStream[] mergeFilesStream = new DataInputStream[selection.size()];
        long[] sizes=new long[selection.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<selection.size(); i++) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ssmultitrackPlus/project1/" +selection.get(i));
         sizes[i] = (file.length()-44)/2;
        }
        for(int i =0; i<selection.size(); i++) {
            mergeFilesStream[i] =new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ssmultitrackPlus/project1/" +selection.get(i))));


           // if(i == selection.size()-1) {
                mergeFilesStream[i].skip(24);
                byte[] sampleRt = new byte[4];
                mergeFilesStream[i].read(sampleRt);
                ByteBuffer bbInt = ByteBuffer.wrap(sampleRt).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = bbInt.getInt();
                mergeFilesStream[i].skip(16);
          //  }
            //    else {
               //     mergeFilesStream[i].skip(44);
           //     }

        }

        for(int b=0; b<selection.size(); b++) {
        for(int i=0; i<(int)sizes[b]; i++) {
             byte[] dataBytes = new byte[2];
             try {
             dataBytes[0] = mergeFilesStream[b].readByte();
             dataBytes[1] = mergeFilesStream[b].readByte();
             }
             catch (EOFException e) {
                amplifyOutputStream.close();
             }
             short dataInShort = ByteBuffer.wrap(dataBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort();
             float dataInFloat= (float) dataInShort/37268.0f;


            short outputSample = (short)(dataInFloat * 37268.0f);
            byte[] dataFin = new byte[2];
           dataFin[0] = (byte) (outputSample & 0xff);
           dataFin[1] = (byte)((outputSample >> 8) & 0xff);        
          amplifyOutputStream.write(dataFin, 0 , 2);

        }
        }
        amplifyOutputStream.close();
        for(int i=0; i<selection.size(); i++) {
            mergeFilesStream[i].close();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long size =0;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileSize = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ssmultitrackPlus/project1/NOVO.wav");
        size = fileSize.getChannel().size();
        fileSize.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;

    long datasize=size+36;
    long byteRate = (RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE)/8;
    long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
    byte[] header = new byte[44];




     header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header 
     header[1] = 'I';
     header[2] = 'F';
     header[3] = 'F';
     header[4] = (byte) (datasize & 0xff);
     header[5] = (byte) ((datasize >> 8) & 0xff);
     header[6] = (byte) ((datasize >> 16) & 0xff);
     header[7] = (byte) ((datasize >> 24) & 0xff);
     header[8] = 'W';
     header[9] = 'A';
     header[10] = 'V';
     header[11] = 'E';
     header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
     header[13] = 'm';
     header[14] = 't';
     header[15] = ' ';
     header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
     header[17] = 0;
     header[18] = 0; 
     header[19] = 0;
     header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
     header[21] = 0;
     header[22] = (byte) 1;
     header[23] = 0;
     header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
     header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
     header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
     header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
     header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
     header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
     header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
     header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
     header[32] = (byte) ((RECORDER_BPP) / 8);  // block align
     header[33] = 0;
     header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
     header[35] = 0;
     header[36] = 'd';
     header[37] = 'a';
     header[38] = 't';
     header[39] = 'a';
     header[40] = (byte) (size & 0xff);
     header[41] = (byte) ((size >> 8) & 0xff);
     header[42] = (byte) ((size >> 16) & 0xff);
     header[43] = (byte) ((size >> 24) & 0xff);
   // out.write(header, 0, 44); 

    try {
         RandomAccessFile rFile = new RandomAccessFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ssmultitrackPlus/project1/NOVO.Wav", "rw");
        rFile.seek(0);
        rFile.write(header);
        rFile.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}
```

O código acima concatena as faixas, eu gostaria que juntasse os dois ou mais sons ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sua lógica esta correta, infelizmente você não mostrou como está tentando fazer em Android, você talvez precise conhecer um pouco de teoria para entender o que está acontecendo com o seu código, qualquer tipo de som pode ser definido como vibrações se propagando pelo ar até chegar em seus ouvidos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você já se perguntou como consegue escutar um vasto número de sons acontecendo simultaneamente?

R: Sem você saber tudo está sendo mixado, todas as vibrações ocorrendo no ambiente se unem e são interpretados pelo seus sistema auditivo!

Computacionalmente estamos simulando o sistema auditivo, se queremos que diferentes origens sonoras se juntem apenas somamos os pulsos vibracionais.

Como fazer isso ?

R: você vai precisar da informação crua para poder manipular seu áudio, isso se aplica para qualquer tipo de manipulação necessária ex: mudar o volume do áudio, alterar a frequência, deixar mais lento ou mais rápido, etc.

Quando eu disse "`informação crua`" eu quero dizer que são os dados do seu áudio antes de sofrer qualquer codificação em mp3, wav, ogg, etc, e para conseguir isso em áudios gravados e codificados é preciso decodificar, para cada formato de áudio você vai encontrar um algoritmo diferente, comece com samples em .wav são mais simples de decodificar/codificar, eu acredito que deva existir uma vasta alternativa em Android para este passo!

OK com os dados decodificados você pode ter um vetor(se o áudio for mono), com os valores manipuláveis, eu aconselho que os valores decodificado fiquem no formato `float point 32bit`, os valores de seu vetor vão estar entre `-1 e 1`.

Com estes dados você pode simplesmente somar os dois vetores decodificados no formato float, para prevenir algum eventual transbordo nos valores com amplitude próximo da extremidade (prevenir ruídos) você pode multiplicar os dois vetores por `0.5` e depois somar, por fim você pode normalizar a saída, um pseudo código com este passo seria:

```
resultado = (vetor1 * 0.5) + (vetor2 * 0.5)
```

Para normalizar encontre o máximo valor absoluto do resultado acima e multiplique pelo resultado

```
Resultado_final_normalizado = (1 / max(abs(resultado))) * resultado
```

Ps: Os dois áudio que você deseja juntar precisar ter o mesmo sample rate, outro ponto a ser observado é se os dois vetores após a decodificação vão possuir o mesmo tamanho, se forem diferentes concatene o vetor menor com `zeros` para ficar do mesmo tamanho!

**EDIT:**

Código usado para juntar três arquivos de áudio:

```
private void mixFiles(){
                try {
                        InputStream is1 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test1);
                        List<Short> music1 = createMusicArray(is1);

                        InputStream is2 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test2);
                        List<Short> music2 = createMusicArray(is2);

                        InputStream is3 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test3);
                        List<Short> music3 = createMusicArray(is3);

                        completeStreams(music1,music2,music3);
                        short[] music1Array = buildShortArray(music1);
                        short[] music2Array = buildShortArray(music2);
                        short[] music3Array = buildShortArray(music3);

                        short[] output = new short[music1Array.length];
                        for(int i=0; i < output.length; i++){

                                float samplef1 = music1Array[i] / 32768.0f;
                                float samplef2 = music2Array[i] / 32768.0f;
                                float samplef3 = music3Array[i] / 32768.0f;

                                float mixed = samplef1 + samplef2 + samplef3;
                                // reduce the volume a bit:
                                mixed *= 0.8;
                                // hard clipping
                                if (mixed > 1.0f) mixed = 1.0f;
                                if (mixed < -1.0f) mixed = -1.0f;
                                short outputSample = (short)(mixed * 32768.0f);


                                output[i] = outputSample;
                        }
                        CHAME_AQUI_SUA_FUNCAO_PARA_SALVAR_EM_WAVE
                } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

Repare na variável `output` ela vai conter os arquivos mixados em raw, chame alguma função que salve o resultado em wave. O código mostrado por você parece ter uma função que escreve o header + data do arquivo para `.wave`, você pode reutilizar este pedaço de código.

O código acima é um pouco diferente do proposto por mim, neste caso ele apenas verifica se a amplitude do sinal é superior a `1` ou `-1` se sim a amplitude é forçada a ficar em seus extremos.

Comment: A normalização dos dados esta errada: como os áudios PCM estão entre `[-1,1]`, e a proporção deles no resultado é 50% cada, o resultado final também estará no intervalo `[-1,1]`. Assim, a expressão `max(abs(resultado))` será sempre no intervalo `[0,1]` que quando operado no vetor `resultado`, irá reduzir os valores das amostragens, reduzindo o volume do som. O correto seria então: `Resultado_final_normalizado = (1.0 / max(abs(resultado))) * resultado`

Comment: Bem lembrado @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira, estou editando a resposta :-)

Comment: De forma que sou apenas um novato, nessa parte, ta faltando bastante coisa nesse fonte, vou ter que estudar bastante pra conseguir juntar essas faixas, mas obrigado pela ajuda...mas por hora não consegui ...

Comment: Poxa que pena o código pra mim é claro como uma manhã ensolarada, se você realmente quer escrever códigos para análise, processamento e manipulação de áudio construa uma boa base matemática/algebrica, leia artigos e livros sobre processamento digital. Entenda o básica como conceitos de sample, frame, taixa de amostragem, etc. Eu consideto Mixar sons da maneira que deseja uma das operações mais simples no domínio do tempo.

Comment: Depois de muito estudar e pesquisar, consegui mixar os wavs, mas ainda estou utilizando essas explicações como base, agora meu problema é outro é otimizar a mixagem...mas isso é assunto pra outro tópico ^^

Comment: muito bom meus parabéns, você acaba de fazer uma das operações mais básicas no domínio do tempo :-), sobre otimização abra uma nova pergunta para que eu ou outra pessoa te auxiliar.