# Mixar vários arquivos binários em PHP

Tags: php

Existe alguma função em PHP para mixar vários arquivos (especificamente, arquivos de áudio) em um só? Eu não quero concatenar os arquivos, e sim somar os índices iguais em um arquivo de destino. Por exemplo: pegar um arquivo de áudio com guitarra e outro com bateria e mixar os dois em um só, para em seguida fazer o download.

Comment: Talvez esses links te ajude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393203/merge-mp3-files-into-one-and-then-save-in-a-folder-using-php   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645438/mixing-2-audio-files-and-return-as-1-using-php

Comment: Valeu Dalton (Y)

Comment: Infelizmente não é o que eu preciso. A classe descrita nesses links serve para concatenar os arquivos. Eu preciso mixa-los.

Comment: Poderia descrever melhor qual/como seria o processo de mixagem?

Comment: Eu preciso tocar um som por streaming, mas as trilhas estão separadas (um arquivo de áudio para cada instrumento). Eu preciso combinar essas trilhas e então fazer o download.

Comment: dá uma olhada nesta pergunta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33673/existe-a-possibilidade-de-juntar-dois-arquivos-de-%C3%A1udio-em-um-s%C3%B3-em-android/34388#34388), a lógica serve para qualquer linguagem, para MP3 você vai precisar de algum decode, não sei se existe nada nativo em PHP.

Comment: Valeu  edervander. É, o maior problema é com a decodificação mesmo. Eu estava mixando os buffers e fazendo o upload de um arquivo apenas para preview. O problema é que eu posso exibir uma lista com todas as trilhas já criadas para todos os sons, com a opção de remoção. Então, se eu tenho um som com guitarra e bateria, e apago a trilha com bateria, o preview não vai se alterar, fazendo com que o som completo se torne inconsistente (tocando ainda a trilha removida).