# Como juntar arquivos de áudio com node js

Tags: node.js, npm, áudio

Eu preciso concatenar 2 arquivos de áudio em formato wav com node.
Eu tenho o "áudio 1" com 5 segundos de duração e o "áudio 2 com 5 segundos de duração"
Preciso gerar o arquivo "áudio 3" com 5 segundos de duração, que contem o conteúdo do áudio 1 e áudio 2 tocando simultaneamente.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você não quer concatenar você quer mixar ...

A maneira mais simples que eu conheço é utilizar o [web-audio-api](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/)

Instale com:

```
npm install web-audio-api
```

Decodifique ambos os arquivos e some os valores dos dois vetores:

```
    var AudioContext = require('web-audio-api').AudioContext
    context = new AudioContext


    var samplerate;
    var pcmdata1 = [] ;
    var pcmdata2 = [] ;
    var mix = [];

    var soundfile1 = "sounds/sound1.wav"
    var soundfile2 = "sounds/sound2.wav"



    decodeSoundFile1(soundfile1);
    decodeSoundFile2(soundfile2);
    mixer();
    playSound(mix)




    //decodificando os dois arquivos

    function decodeSoundFile1(soundfile){
      console.log("decoding file ", soundfile, " ..... ")
      fs.readFile(soundfile, function(err, buf) {
        if (err) throw err
        context.decodeAudioData(buf, function(audioBuffer) {
          console.log(audioBuffer.numberOfChannels, audioBuffer.length, audioBuffer.sampleRate, audioBuffer.duration);
          pcmdata1 = (audioBuffer.getChannelData(0)) ;
          samplerate=audioBuffer.sampleRate;
        }, function(err) { throw err })
      })
    }


   function decodeSoundFile2(soundfile){
      console.log("decoding file ", soundfile, " ..... ")
      fs.readFile(soundfile, function(err, buf) {
        if (err) throw err
        context.decodeAudioData(buf, function(audioBuffer) {
          console.log(audioBuffer.numberOfChannels, audioBuffer.length, audioBuffer.sampleRate, audioBuffer.duration);
          pcmdata2 = (audioBuffer.getChannelData(0)) ;
        }, function(err) { throw err })
      })
    }



  //mixando os arquivos


  function mixer() {
      for (var i = 0; i < pcmdata1.length; i++) 
           mix[i] = pcmdata1[i] + pcmdata2[i]

}

  //tocando o áudio mixado no browser

  function playSound(arr) {
    var buf = new Float32Array(arr.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) buf[i] = arr[i]
    var buffer = context.createBuffer(1, buf.length, samplerate)
    buffer.copyToChannel(buf, 0)
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0);
}
```

claro você pode substituir a função que toca o áudio por outra que codifique o áudio em um arquivo wav ou mp3, eu fiz rapidamente o código e não tratei muitas coisas que pode ser importante, ambos os arquivos de áudio tem que ter exatamente do mesmo tamanho, você pode tratar no código se quiser mais tarde, ambos arquivos decodificados também tem que possuir a mesma taxa de amostragem ...

Eu explico [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33673/existe-a-possibilidade-de-juntar-dois-arquivos-de-%C3%A1udio-em-um-s%C3%B3-em-android/34388#34388) como isso é feito em java, a lógica e os passos são os mesmos para qualquer linguagem!